# $\mathbb E(Y|X)$ for the normal distribution $(X,Y,Z)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $(X,Y,Z)$ a normal trivariate distribution, with expectation $0$, i.e. $$(\mathbb E(X), \mathbb E(Y), \mathbb E(Z)) = (0,0,0)$$ and matrix of variances-covariances $$\begin{pmatrix}
    1      & 0  & \alpha \\
    0      & 1  & \beta \\
    \alpha      & \beta  & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

It's easy to see that 
 $$\mathbb E(Y|X) = 0 \hspace{1cm} \text{and} \hspace{1cm}  \mathbb E(Y|X,Z) = \frac{-\alpha \beta}{1-\beta^2}X + \frac{\alpha}{1-\beta^2}Z.$$

Unfortunately I'm blind and unable to see that! I see that $\mathbb E(XY)=0$ and $\mathbb E(XZ)= \alpha$ and $\mathbb E(Y,Z) = \beta$.

Thanks!

Comment: @Henry Edited, thanks!

Comment: The covariance matrix and vector of means characterise a joint normal distribution, so you can write down the joint distribution $p(x, y, z)$ of the random variables $(X, Y, Z)$ using just the vector $(0, 0, 0)$ and the matrix you wrote down (which is typically denoted $\Sigma$). Note that $E[Y | X, Z] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y p(y | X, Z) dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y \frac{p(X, y, Z)}{\int_{-\infty}^\infty p(X, y, Z)} dy$. An easy one is $E[Y | X] = 0$, because $E[XY] = 0$ and for normal random variables uncorrelated implies independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $(X,Y,Z)$ are jointly normal, the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X, Z$ is a linear combination of $X$ and $Z$, expressible in matrix algebra as:
$$
E(Y\mid X,Z) = E(Y)+\left[ \operatorname{cov}(Y,X)\ \ \operatorname{cov}(Y,Z)\right]\left[
\begin{matrix}
  \operatorname{var}(X) & \operatorname{cov}(X,Z) \\
  \operatorname{cov}(Z,X) & \operatorname{var}(Z)
 \end{matrix}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{matrix}
  X-EX \\
  Z-EZ
 \end{matrix}\right]
$$
Plug in the particulars of your problem and grind it through. The general result can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/30588/145128).